# Integral exists over the closure but not the set itself

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus

Is there an open set $S$ with a bounded function $f$ such that $\int_\overline{S}f$ exists but $\int_Sf$ does not?

Comment: What definition of integral are you using? Lebesgue?